# Ubuntu 18.04 - prevent displays from sleeping on Lock

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, suspend, lock-screen

I can lock my screen using `Super + L` keyboard shortcut or the button on the top right corner of the desktop (along with the power and settings) but this immediately turns my monitors off. I want to be able to lock my screen, display the clock and dashboard, and re-login quickly without having to wake my monitors.

The GUI solutions using Tweaks and the standard preferences don't help this.

What piece of software is deciding to turn off the screens, so I can try to troubleshoot this further?

Comment: Lots of people have complained about this but I've yet to see an accepted answer

Comment: Do you know what software is responsible for making this sleep decision? I'll start using this questions as a compilation of the results to try and figure this out.

Comment: It's one of my long term projects to figure this out plus make it easy to change the login screen wallpaper. Hopefully someone else has made more progress and will pony up an answer for you though.

Comment: I was able to change the login screen wallpaper easily enough by modifying the file at `/etc/alternatives/gdm3.css` - this is a permanent solution and it makes sense that it works (albeit a little tedious to do without a gui). Is gdm3 making the decision to sleep the monitors after lock, as well?